# Time delay for execution of setTimeout doubles or even triples after each mouseEvent even with hard coded delay;

Tags: javascript

```js
function toggleDetail(e){
    el = e.target || e.srcElement;
    flag=false;
    if(timer>0){
        console.log(timer);
        timer=0;
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(card=>{
        card.style.zIndex="0"
    });
    if(allowedElements.includes(el.className) && el.className==="card")
        reactUnmount(el.children[5]);
    else
    if(allowedElements.includes(el.className) && el.className!=="card"){
        el = el.parentNode
        if(el.className==="card")
            reactUnmount(el.children[5]);
    }
    if(el.className==="detailCard"){
        el = el.parentNode
        console.log(el.className)
    }
}
function mouseEnter(e){
    if(screenSize>768){
        el = e.target || e.srcElement;
        e.stopPropagation()
        
        if(allowedElements.includes(el.className)){
            if(el.className!=="card-heading"){
                flag=false;
            }
            else{
                el = el.parentNode;
                flag=true
            }
        }
        if(el.className==="card"){
            if(flag){
                flag=false
                console.time("mouseOver");
                timer = window.setTimeout((el)=>{
                    mouseOver(el);
                    console.timeEnd("mouseOver");
                },2000,el)
            }else if(!flag) {
                toggleDetail(e)
            }
        }
        else{
            toggleDetail(e)
        }
    }
}
```

This block of code troubling me a lot. I don't understand why the time delay keeps on increasing on each mouseEvent.

Output:

```
mouseOver: 2214.14794921875 ms
mouseOver: 2498.247314453125 ms
mouseOver: 2999.162841796875 ms
mouseOver: 4748.389892578125 ms
mouseOver: 11913.559814453125 ms
mouseOver: 30919.48388671875 ms
```

and so on...

I'm trying to detect if mouse is hovered on an element for 2 seconds. If yes, then I will pop a modal or else I'll clearTimeout.

Please send suggestions and also if possible explain me how this delay keeps on increasing?

Comment: The site designers have chosen the font and font weight for text in order to maximize legibility for the majority of readers (at least in theory). Please don't degrade that by making everything boldface.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).